# Issue with session_start and session.gc_maxlifetime

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

I want to set session.gc_maxlifetime. but the value of timeout is itself in session.
I tried using below code but it does't work.

```
session_start();

//Do some database and session operations

ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', $_SESSION['timeout'] );

session_start();
```

Comment: You have a dynamic changing timeout for php session? why?

Comment: I get timeout seconds from database after a long processing.

Comment: what does database timeout have anything to do with php session timeout? Are you sure you aren't getting max execution timeout? In any case, why don't you set the respective timeouts globally on `php.ini`?

Comment: We dont have access of php.ini. Also user-wise timeouts are stored in database. Once user logges in after that I get timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set session.gc_maxlifetime by timeout of your session, i guess this approach is totally wrong,

it is because session settings should be defined before beginning of the session.

Try this-

```
$timeout=$_SESSION['timeout']

$old_session_id = session_id();

# write and close current session
session_write_close();


ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $timeout);

# now we can switch the session over, capturing the old session name
$old_session_name = session_name($session_name);
session_id($session_id);
session_start();

# get the desired session data
$session_data = $_SESSION;
```

Comment: I get $_SESSION['timeout'] in my application from any other application where it is getting set.

Comment: but the session for both the applications are same! are'nt they? ok. i am editing my answer, try something like this. perhaps, this should do it. wait.

Comment: User-wise timeouts are stored in database. Once user logges in after that I get timeout value

Comment: What i am trying to say is, you cannot alter session settings when the session is running. for doing this, first you need to close the session and then you can alter them.

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to close the session without loosing its values-> set timeout-> start it using session_start(). Is it possible?

Comment: yes, i had shown it above, remember, just close it but dont destroy it.

Comment: its not needed, session id will remain the same, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using below code.

```
$arrMixTempSession = $_SESSION;
session_destroy();

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $_SESSION['timeout'] * 60 );
session_start();

$_SESSION = $arrMixTempSession;
```